# Skip plots containing fewer than 10 points in facet_wrap -- accessing ggplot data points

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to skip `geom_point` plots in `facet_wrap` when the plot contains less than 10 data points?

I am using a code like this:

```r
ggplot(data) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = Height, Y = Weight, shape = Gender, col = InstrumentUsed)) + 
    facet_wrap(ID ~ Institute, drop = T)
```

**I have two problems**:

1. If out of `x` and `y` one is full of NA values, the plot still shows up in the `facet` as an empty plot. I do not want such plots to be printed. But it looks like just because one of the provided columns is non-NA/non-empty, ggplot still plots such an empty plot!
2. If there are **less than 10 data points in a single plot**, I do not want the plot to be printed at all.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to access the underlying structure of a `ggplot` object and easily filter those objects that contain less than 10 datapoints?

**EXAMPLE DATA**

This can be loaded via `dget`:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1chulcK5yinAOE6R11UKyi6IFekdNvyaa

e.g.

```
data <- dget("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1chulcK5yinAOE6R11UKyi6IFekdNvyaa")
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data, so your problem becomes reproducible?
In general in these kind of situations I think bringing the data in the appropriate format is easier than hacking through ggplot.

Comment: I agree with Mojosque. Probably you want to filter these out of your `data` data.frame before starting your plot. For  example: `splitdata <- split(data, interaction(data$ID, data$Institute))`, then checking the rows of each split for NA's, e.g. `nr.nas <- lapply(splitdata, function(df){sum(is.na(df[,c("Height", "Weight", "Gender", "InstrumentUsed"))})` and subsequently filtering by `splitdata <- splitdata[nr.nas < 10]` and then re-combinding your data `data <- do.call(rbind, splitdata)`. I haven't tested the code, so be wary.

Comment: Thank you @teunbrand. Your recommendation also worked! It also worked for filtering groups with fewer than 10 data points; `mydimdf <- lapply(split(data, interaction(data$ID, data$Institute)), function(df){dim(df)[1]}); splitdata[mydimdf > 10]; data <- do.call(rbind, splitdata)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in this case a very simple solution would just be to remove any rows containing `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse)
data = dget("data.txt") %>%
  as_tibble()

data = data %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.))

#All remaining groups have more than 10 data points:
> data %>% 
+   group_by(ID, Institute) %>%
+   group_size()
[1]  916 1674  607  831  179 1386   55  968 4002

#Edit: If you want to exclude groups with a certain number of datapoints
#      (55 in this case to exclude at least one group) you could do 
#      something like this: 

data_cleaned = data %>%
  group_by(ID, Institute) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n >55)
```

Plotting the data without removal of small groups:

```
ggplot(data) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Height, y = Weight, shape = Gender, col = InstrumentUsed)) + 
  facet_wrap(ID ~ Institute, drop = T)
```

[image]

Plotting the data with small groups removed:

```
ggplot(data_cleaned) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Height, y = Weight, shape = Gender, col = InstrumentUsed)) + 
  facet_wrap(ID ~ Institute, drop = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This indeed solves my first problem. But my other (main) problem is that I do not at all want to print plots that contain fewer than 10 data points. In other words, if in a certain plot in the facet above there are only 10 data points (or fewer) then that plot should not show up, even though there are 10 complete pairs of height and weight. Perhaps this can be somehow achieved by `dplyr`? (e.g. `group_by(ID, Institute)` and exclude groups that have fewer than 10 datapoints recorded in either height or weight)?

Comment: Does you problem refer to a different dataset? Because after removal of any rows containing `NA` each group has more than 10 data points. See my eddit in the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that! I have an enormous dataset and I only chose a very small portion of it due to its size. In fact, 'height' and 'weight' are only two of my parameters. I have over 100 parameters, and I am looping over them and generating such correlation plots for each pair of parameters. In many of parameters it happens that I do have only fewer than 10 datapoints for a pair.

Comment: Ah I see, it would have been easier if one of these groups was included in the sample data. But anyway, I added a potential solution to my answer. I just filtered by group size. Would such a solution be feasible for your dataset?

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Much appreciated.